# Butter coffee taste and effects?

Tags: bulletproof

I have heard of people putting grass fed unsalted butter in their coffee and I have heard its pretty good. I was wondering if anyone has tried it and would like to describe the taste and how effective it was.

Comment: I recommend you to search for Bulletproof coffee. I believe you search for that. If this is the case, you may think of updating your question.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this will be a good answer for you but here it goes.

When I lived in France (small rural community), I used to put grass fed unsalted butter into my coffee all the time. I got the idea from reading articles about Tibetans putting [yak butter into their black tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butter_tea).

Personally I enjoy it. It is an acquired taste because it is has a very rich and heavy flavor. Do not put milk or cream into your coffee as it will completely change your perspective on this great coffee idea. For myself, I prefer not to drink it just as it, safe the bottom of the barrel sort of speaking. I generally would dunk my rather dense bread (sometimes biscuits) into it at breakfast time and have enjoyed doing this as such for many years.

For myself I only do this in the mornings.

Answer (score 2):

I tried "bulletproof coffee" recipe using a different brand of organic coffee and mixed in butter and coconut oil (instead of MTC oil). The coffee tasted creamy with a buttery/oily after taste. You can taste both the coconut and butter. If you're used to drinking strong coffee with cream this is not that much of a stretch. The effect of the caffeine in the coffee does last longer.

**Now let's talk about the effect**

Bulletproof coffee or butter coffee was derived from the traditional [Butter tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butter_tea) used in the Tibet and the Himalayas. In the region a higher caloric density Yak butter is used.

MCT oil, which is also present in sufficient amounts in coconut oil (coconut oil also has higher amounts to HDL cholesterol to negligible LDL cholesterol, which is good) is an addition in tweaking the traditional butter tea to achive a Cognitive Enhancement. [LDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-density_lipoprotein) is essential to repair and maintain the [Myelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myelin) sheath of neurons as such to good neural activity of the brain, [MCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-chain_triglyceride) oil do not require energy for absorption, utilization, or storage. This means that MCT is generally considered a good biologically inert source of energy that the human body finds reasonably easy to metabolize. So in other words it provides a great energy boost with almost no fat storage. As such coconut oil constituting both, also metabolises into ketone bodies more efficiently than any other dietary substance, (Ketones may improve cognitive functioning) gives you a mental boot. MCT [have been tested to improve cognitive functioning](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15123336). [MCTs also produce more ketones](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/5166216) per unit of energy than normal dietary fats. (Note: higher [Ketonema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketosis) is achieved with low Carb intake, following through can give body a non starvation ketosis effect)

Other effects of butter coffee is that it helps your body regulate [Insulin resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin_resistance) blood sugar levels and the hormone [Leptin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptin) (hormone responsible for body fat regulation, metabolism, breaking down fact for energy rather than storing).  Which in turn also has a cascading effect on your hunger signaling hormone [Ghrelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghrelin), without the hormone being secreted you will feel full for a long time (granted you did not take carbohydrate of any sort with the coffee, this is important as carbohydrates will trigger the fats to be stored in your body rather than broken down for energy, and later on will trigger ghrelin after the crabs run out).

But will it help you lose weight? Personally I felt, Uh, no!!!  Drinking coffee (in general) is liable to give you more energy, which may help motivate you to be more active, but only assuming you don't already drink a lot of caffiene.  Otherwise, all you're doing is offsetting the withdrawal symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

I thought the taste was incredible... I'm used to sipping on straight black all day, but the fat addition made it so rich it was hard to drink a large amount.
It definitely changed the caffeine response for me personally; slower rise and fall in energy overall.

Practical Tip: It definitely isn't as easy as just adding a pat to you mug. The best results are when you get the butter fully emulsified in the coffee; think about blending the freshly brewed black coffee and butter together for the best effect. Otherwise you just get an unappealing layer of fat floating on top of the regular black coffee rather than the nice mixture.

Answer (score 1):

On top of other comments, one large community that benefits the effects of "Bulletproof Coffee" are people on a Ketogenic diet (high fat, low carb). I'm currently on keto and have 3-5 BulletProof coffees a week; it definitely fills you up and the butter gives the coffee a different creaminess than with milk. If you use MCT oil, make sure to get "flavorless", otherwise it can add an overbearing taste.